# narrow down mapped type value types

Tags: typescript, generics, mapped-types

The use case is as follows:

First, I have an interface called `Test1` which maps between a certain key and a type.
Next, I have a second interface, `Test2`, which maps between those same keys and different types.
Third, I have functions (as values in `mapper` object) that know how to map between the first to the second.

Essentially, the use case is the need to map between different objects that are connected by some key,
but to make it as generic as possible while constraint by the interfaces that holds the mappings.

The following code

```
interface Test1 {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

interface Test2 {
  a: object;
  b: Array<number>;
}

type Mapper = {
  [P in keyof Test1]: (param: Test2[P]) => Test1[P];
};

const mapper: Mapper = {
  a: (param: object) => 123,
  b: (param: Array<number>) => 'asd'
};

function test<T extends keyof Test1>(type: T, msg: Test2[T]): Test1[T] {
  const func = mapper[type];
  return func(msg);
}
```

throws the following exception when trying to pass `msg` to `func`:

```
Argument of type `Test2[T]` is not assignable to parameter of type `number[]`.
```

In this example, lets assume `type` will be equal to `'a'`, then I want to receive the function that the `mapper` holds as value of key `'a'` and use it on the `msg` I have.

I did see [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728#issuecomment-479542352)` issue when searching for a solution, but I thought maybe my case is differnet,
reason being that I'm using a mapped type.

Any way to work this out?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that the type of `func` is inferred to be `(param: object & number[]) => 'number | string'` which narrows to `(param: number[]) => 'number | string'` The typescript compiler is simply not smart enough to realize that the parameters signature of `func` always matches `Test2[T]`.

Unfortunately, your best solution is probably to just cast and tell the compiler that you know better.

```
function test<T extends keyof Test1>(type: T, msg: Test2[T]): Test1[T] {
  const func = mapper[type] as any;
  return func(msg);
}
```